# CSS max-height and overflow auto always displays vertical scroll

Tags: scroll, overflow, css

I have a div class set up with the following CSS style:

```
div.multiple_choice{
    border: 1px solid black; 
    max-width: 300px; 
    max-height: 200px; 
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The problem is, when the text inside doesn't force the DIV to reach the maximum height of 200px, the vertical scroll bar still shows up.  I can click on the up and down arrows but it only moves the contents up and down by about a pixel or two.

This is occuring in Google Chrome (version 18.0) and Iceweasel 11.

Comment: Need to see a test case. I can't verify this on a test page in Firefox (unless Iceweasel's using a really old build of Gecko).

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Iceweasel has the same version numbering as Firefox, so 11 is the latest release.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As it turns out, another CSS style was causing the issue:

```
body{
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Anyone interested in learning about how and why this would cause an issue, can read about the line-height property [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp)

Comment: Your link doesn't explain how/why `line-height` would cause this issue.

Comment: @nuclearpenguin, So _how_ does `line-height` have any affect on the scroll?  There's nothing in your link

Comment: I also experienced this issue. Setting `line-height` to `normal` on the elements inside the div fixed it.

Comment: Kuba Orlik's solution (`line-height:normal`) was the only solution that worked for me

Comment: i faced the same issue  , setting line-height to the element solved my issue Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 7):

Just to put in evidence the **@Kuba Orlik**'s solution (he posted as comment on the accepted answer) that's the only one that worked for me.

Add this on inside elements:

```
line-height: normal;
```

**Note**: Explicitly `normal` not `1` because it's different

Comment: Worked like a charm. Side note:  postiton:sticky is also related concept when you want to have non-scrollable within the scrollable div. check from 15 min onwards here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UO8ed-JB4So

Answer (score 6):

I was having an issue with this, and I found that having `position: relative` on the child elements was causing the problem. Obviously this can't be the solution for everyone, especially if `position: absolute` is being used, but for me it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I added this `padding-bottom: 1px` to the `overflow: auto` div and it seems to be fixed for me..

Comment: I also had this issue, content was much less than the allowed max height but was still showing the scroll bar. adding a padding-bottom value fixed the issue. Anyone know why that fixes it though?

Answer (score 4):

I have encounter this problem.But I solved  this use the following css style:

```
div.yourcontainer{overflow-y:auto;}
```

If the container was higher than max-height,the vertical scrollbar will show.

Comment: It seems strange to me that this is the second-highest voted answer. I get that it's helped some users but **it totally misses the point of the question**: they already used `overflow: auto` and were still always seeing the scrollbar. Please don't upvote blindly.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when trying to wrap a list (flex column) of react components in a div, I resolved it by changing margin of elements within each list item to be 0.

The approach to troubleshoot this for me was to inspect the list items (perhaps each `<li>` in OP) and see what styles were making the div think each list item was larger than what was visible to the human eye.

Here is an example of inspecting a rogue margin on an icon within a list item in my project:
[image: Example of rogue margin]

Solution is to set the style of that icon to have a vertical margin of 0, though in my application I just made all the margin 0 and added some padding-right.

[image: Fixed rogue margin example]

Comment: Awesome! Setting margin: 0 worked for me.
I had set margin-bottom as a minus value for the child items, which is why this bug was appearing.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the vertical scroll is obvious: the scrolled content is higher than scrolling area. But when you observe their heights, they are equal!

The causes are multiple but all come down to a common one: an element *inside* the scrolled content overflows it and makes the result taller.

How to fix this?

1. find the guilty element by looking near the bottom edge of the scrolled element (or to the right if you're scrolling horizontally), because they are the most likely to overflow. You should observe a height larger that their parent's.
2. see what makes them overflow, be larger than their container. As other answers suggest, it can be `line-height`, some `margin`, etc. Change those properties to make them fit, or as an alternative, set `overflow-y: hidden` to their immediate parent.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem using Bootstrap and nav.  It occurred because bootstrap definds the li in nav-tabs as: `.nav-tabs > li { margin-bottom:-1px; }`.  To counteract this, you must also do:

```
.nav-tabs > li:last-child {
   margin-bottom:0;
}
```

---

Without setting the last-child, the following example would always show scroll, no matter how much content is in the list:

```
<ul class="navs nav-tabs nav-stacked" style="max-height:80px;overflow:auto;">
  <li></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this bug earlier today. In my case a list of child elements had display: inline-block instead of display: block. Switching to display: block for my list of child elements in the truncated div fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was with the font. We use `font-family: Galano Grotesque`. Apparently, this font is rendered higher than the computed height.

```
<div>
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

So even without `max-height`, when the inner `p` and the outer `div` were both computed as `20px` height, there was still a scroll bar (with `overflow: auto`) because the font was about `1px` higher than expected.

So the solution can be any one of:

- Use a different font.
- Add `padding` to the outer `div`. This way it will be large enough to cover the extra pixel that comes from the font. In my case, adding one pixel of padding to the bottom and one to the top solved the problem.
- Set `line-height` to a bit larger value (in my case, from `1.25` to `1.4`), so it won't interfere with the font.
- Set `line-height` to `normal` because then the actual value will be influenced by the font. However, [according to Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height), this is not the preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got one more element with pos absolute inside element with overflow auto. And prop bottom: -1px; created this problem. Solved with bottom: 0;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).